# Separate URL access environment with nginx using proxy_pass and root

Tags: nginx

I want to use "/ddd", "/api" and "/" in the URLs to access them separately.
The "/" and "/api" settings in proxy_pass will work.
However, it fails when I try to access the "/ddd" file.

```
server {
    listen       443 default ssl;
    server_name *.domain.co.jp
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /ssl/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/domain.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.3:80/;
    }
    location /ddd/ {
        root   /var/www/html;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.4:80/;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I think it is a problem with the setting because I was able to access "/var/www/html" from HTML when I modified it as follows.

```
server {
    listen       443 default ssl;
    server_name *.domain.co.jp
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /ssl/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/domain.key;
#    location / {
#        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.3:80/;
#    }
    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.4:80/;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help I can get from you.
Thank you for your help.

### 2020/10/27 15:58 add

I tried to change the order, but it was a 404 error.
I tried commenting out the last "/" or other OPTIONs but it was the same.
Only "/ddd" is still inaccessible.

```
    location /ddd {
#        index index.html;
#        autoindex on;
        root /var/www/html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.3:80/;
#    root /var/www/html;
    }
```

### add 2020/10/27 16:39

File Access

```
ls -al /var/www/html
total 372
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  4096 Oct 27 07:31  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root      4096 Oct  5 08:41  ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 17127 Oct 27 04:42  index.html
```

Comment: Thanh Nguyen Van-san Thank you.But it didn't work well. I should add.

Answer (score 0):

We have a solution.
The reason was that the path requested to the system was `/var/www/html/ddd/index.html` if you don't use alias instead of root.

```
    location /ddd {
        index index.html;
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.3:80/;
    }
```